# Xamarin.Forms iOS application failed to deploy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, hot-reload

When I start deploying to my iPhone I'm getting this error. Did someone encounter this? The application is built on Xamarin.Forms and I'm trying to deploy using Hot Restart.

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.5.5

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.2.0.5 (7738c90c9)

Xamarin   17.5.0.173 (d17-5@33e727c)

> Xamarin.iOS.Windows.HotRestartClient Error: 0 : Deploy Error: Could
> not find an app content at:
> C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\NeedAHero.iOS.app\out\myApp.iOS.content:
> 05/10/2023 18:14:27Z  DateTime=2023-05-10T18:14:27.2452669Z:
> 05/10/2023 18:14:27Z
> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.DeployAppMessageHandler Error: 0 : An
> error occurred while trying to deploy the app 'myApp.iOS.app'.
> Details: Could not find an app content at:
> C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\myApp.iOS.app\out\myApp.iOS.content
> Xamarin.iOS.Windows.WindowsiOSException: Could not find an app content
> at:
> C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\myApp.iOS.app\out\myApp.iOS.content
> at Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Installer.ApplicationSession.Deploy(String
> appRootFolder, String appBundleId, String appName) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Tools\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client\Installer\ApplicationSession.cs:line
> 75    at Xamarin.iOS.Windows.HotRestartClient.Deploy(AppleDevice
> nativeDevice, String appBundleId, String appBundleName, Boolean&
> incremental) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Tools\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client\HotRestartClient.cs:line
> 250    at
> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.DeployAppMessageHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\Handlers\DeployAppMessageHandler.cs:line
> 41: 05/10/2023 18:14:27Z
> DateTime=2023-05-10T18:14:27.2452669Z: 05/10/2023 18:14:27Z

Comment: Could you please help share your device iOS version, Xcode version and Visual Studio version?